# Why don't the cell organelles settle down in the cell under the influence of gravity?

Tags: cell-biology, cytoskeleton, organelle

In cuboidal or columnar cells or cells of any other shape the nucleus and the other organelles and inclusions remain suspended in the cytoplasm. Why doesn't gravity affect them ?
Could this be because all organelles are of colloidal size ?
Or is it the result of being held in position microfilaments and other cytoskeletal structures that facilitate cytoplasmic streaming ?

Comment: It's the cytoskeleton - cells are surprisingly full of it.

Comment: okay thanks....got it